# How to move mails from one linked Exchange mailbox to another in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, exchange-server

I have an Exchange mailbox linked as a table in an MS Access app. This is primarily used for reading, but I would also like to be able to "move" messages to another folder.

Unfortunately this is not as simple as writing in a second linked mailbox, because   apparently I can not edit some fields. Some critical fields like the To: field are unavailable, as I get the following error

*"Field 'To' is based on an expression and cannot be edited".*

Using *CreateObject("Outlook.Application")* instead is not an option here, because as far as I know, this gives a security dialog when called from Access.

Any solutions?*

Answer (score 1):

Is this two problems? Mail can be moved using the Move method. Here is a snippet:

```
 Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set oMailItems = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set itm = oMailItems.Items(6)
itm.Move oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
```

However, Recipients (To) is read only, even, I believe, with Outlook Redemtion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Access is the right tool for the job. You will not get around using an Outlook.Application object or a MAPI wrapper like CDO. CDO will be the more elegant and performant way, but it must explicitly be installed on the client via Office Setup.

If you want to avoid the script security dialog (and some of the CDO incapabilities in general), you should give [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) a try.

Redemption is a drop-in replacement for CDO and you will be instantly familiar to it when you did any CDO/Outlook VBA coding before.

Answer (score 0):

To move emails from one linked Exchange mailbox to another in MS Access, first create a new table to store the email data. Then, use the Outlook object model to retrieve the emails from the source mailbox and insert them into the new table. Finally, use the Outlook object model again to send the emails to the destination mailbox.

For example, if you need to move a series of emails containing information on how to perform a [pdf slides free download](https://www.slidesharedown.net/), you can retrieve them from the source mailbox, save them to the new table, and then send them to the destination mailbox for further review and sharing.